# xgettext incorrectly sorts strings

Tags: string, i18n

I'm trying to produce translation files from C sources with translation entries coming in the exact same order as they appear in the sources. I do **not** want them sorted alphabetically, or coming in random order, as some strings are sorted in a domain-specific order which must be kept. I have the following test file:

```
char * elements[] = {gettext("Hydrogen"), gettext("Helium"), gettext("Lithium")};
```

I'm using `xgettext -F test.c`, which according to the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xgettext) is supposed to sort by location:

> `-F`, `--sort-by-file`
>
>   sort output by file location

However, the output appears to be sorted alphabetically:

```
#: test.c:1
msgid "Helium"
msgstr ""

#: test.c:1
msgid "Hydrogen"
msgstr ""

#: test.c:1
msgid "Lithium"
msgstr ""
```

Could someone explain how `-F` (and `-s`, which is supposed to sort alphabetically) work, exactly? Did I miss a flag which sorts by location inside a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments in the output file give a clue. 
Apparently `-F` is sorting *by **line number**,*
and then sorting alphabetically within each line. 
Simply changing the input to

```
char * elements[] = {gettext("Hydrogen"),
                     gettext("Helium"),
                     gettext("Lithium")};
```

yields

```
#: test2.c:1
msgid "Hydrogen"
msgstr ""

#: test2.c:2
msgid "Helium"
msgstr ""

#: test2.c:3
msgid "Lithium"
msgstr ""
```

Comment: Changing the input will be way too much work. Besides, we use `clang-format` with a column limit of 170 characters per line and penalties for useless extra lines, so it will probably not accept such changes.